# C++ - Refactor a long parameter list with references into a struct

Tags: c++

I like to have classes which have a valid state simply after calling their constructor - i.e. all required dependencies are passed into the constructor.

I also like required dependencies to be passed as references, because then nullptr is simply forbidden at compile-time as a value for these arguments.

Example:

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    A(B& b) : b(b) {}

private:
    B& b;
}
```

After instantiating A, you are (almost) guaranteed that the instance is in a valid state. I find that code style to be very safe from programming mistakes.

My question relates to refactoring such classes when they have lots of dependencies.

Example:

```
// Includes for B, C, D, E, F...

class A
{
public:
    A(B b, C c, D d, E e, F f) : b(b), c(c), d(d), e(e), f(f) {}

private:
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    E e;
    F f;
}
```

Usually, I put long lists of parameters in structs, like this:

```
struct Deps
{
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    E e;
    F f;
}

class A
{
public:
    A(Deps deps) : b(deps.b), c(deps.c), d(deps.d), e(deps.e), f(deps.f) {}

private:
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    E e;
    F f;
}
```

That way, it makes the call sites more explicit and less error prone as well: since all parameters must be named, you are not at risk of mistakenly switching two of them by having them in a wrong order.

Sadly, that technique works badly with references. Having references in the Deps struct forwards the problem to that struct: then, the Deps struct needs to have a constructor which initializes the references, and then that constructor will have a long parameter list, essentially solving nothing.

Now for the question: is there a way to refactor long parameter lists in constructors containing references, such that no function results in having a long parameter list, all parameters are always valid, and no instance of the class is ever in an invalid state (i.e. with some dependencies not initialized or null)?

Comment: Note that storing references means you can't implement an assignment operator. Pointers avoid that problem. You could consider accepting references in the constructor but storing pointers. Might also be a non-issue for you.

Comment: _"since all parameters must be named, you are not at risk of mistakenly switching two of them by having them in a wrong order."_ Do they all have the same type? Or why would switching them up not result in a compiler error?

Comment: This question boils down to "at which point do you want to check for completeness of the provided references". The constructor argument list guarantees that they are all provided _because_ they are in the same place. The `Deps` struct is the polar opposite: It can be built up incrementally (at least that seems to be the intention) in order to _avoid_ all dependencies having to be provided at the same place. Those are contradictory, and it's not clear where you want the compromise to be. I'll suggest something in an answer, but maybe you could clarify whether I misunderstood anything.

Comment: And finally, I need to point out that none of this prevents you from holding dangling references/pointers. It's immaterial to the question itself, but I would not consider large networks of plain references/pointers to be intrinsically "very safe from programming mistakes". Again, this does depend on your specific situation though.

Comment: *"I find that code style to be very safe from programming mistakes"* oh boy... 100% of the time I found code where the ref was stored as above, it was a programmer mistake. 99% of the time this is a bad idea.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I am talking about the general case - *if* some parameters have the same type, then the compiler will not catch an ordering mistake.

Comment: @MaxLanghof You are completely right in your analysis of the semantics (argument list vs struct). I have actually only realized the contradiction by reading your comment, so thanks for that. I guess the answer is simply that there is no way to keep all the compile-time checks as I wish it was possible.

Comment: @MaxLanghof And yes, I am well aware that you can still have dangling references. I was actually implicitly talking about the fact that references are saf*er* than pointers in the sense that they cannot be null, thus removing one possible mistake.

Comment: @UmNyobe I am curious as to why you find that a bad idea. The intent behind the code style is to express a dependency between two classes when there is no ownership involved - i.e. you know for a fact that class B will outlive class A. How would you express such an intent in code, if not as described above?

Comment: `you know for a fact that class B will outlive class A`  we like to think our assumptions are set into stone. And sometimes, we do enforce unnecessary design decisions based on these assumptions. The issue here is that a user of class A has no programmatic way to verify if the assumption holds. If you were using a weak pointer, you will have the same + ability to check assumption.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a cake and eat it, too. Well, unless you'd use magic (also known as more powerful types).

The key idea of having the constructor take all necessary dependencies is to make sure they are all provided because the construction happens, and enforcing this statically. If you move this burden to a structure, this structure should only be passed to a constructor if all fields have been filled. If you have unwrapped references, it's obviously impossible to have this structure be only partially filled, and you can't really prove to the compiler that you'll provide the required parameters later.

You can do a run-time check, of course, but that's not what we're after. Ideally, we'd be able to encode which parameters have been initialized in the type itself. This is quite hard to implement in a generic way and only slightly easier if you make some concessions and hand-write it for specific types.

Consider a simplified example in which the types don't repeat in a signature (e.g. the signature of the constructor is `ctor(int, bool, string)`). We can then use `std::tuple` to represnt partially filled argument list like so:

```
auto start = tuple<>();
auto withIntArg = push(42, start);
auto withStringArg = push("xyz"s, withIntArg);
auto withBoolArg = push(true, withStringArg);
```

I've used `auto`, but if you think about types of those variables, you'll realize that it will reach the desired `tuple<int, string, bool>` only after all of those have been executed (albeit in random order). Then you can write the class constructor as a template accepting only tuples that indeed have all required types, write the `push` function and voila!

Of course, this is a lot of boilerplate and a potential for very nasty errors, unless you take a lot of care writing the above. Any other solution you'd like to do would need to effectively do the same thing; *modifying the type of the partially filled argument list* until it fits the desired set.

Is it worth it? Well, you decide for yourself.

Comment: Smart solution, and indeed keeps all the run-time checks I like. In the end though, I think I would personally rather have long parameter lists than complex code at the call sites. I tend to dislike using template tricks because the reader needs to understand them before understanding the meaning of the code itself - thus doubling the amount of work. Still, +1 for the good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a pretty elegant/simple solution using `std::tuple`:

```
#include <tuple>

struct A{};
struct B{};
struct C{};
struct D{};
struct E{};
struct F{};

class Bar
{
public:
    template<class TTuple>
    Bar(TTuple refs)
        : a(std::get<A&>(refs))
        , b(std::get<B&>(refs))
        , c(std::get<C&>(refs))
        , d(std::get<D&>(refs))
        , e(std::get<E&>(refs))
        , f(std::get<F&>(refs))
    {
    }

private:
    A& a;
    B& b;
    C& c;
    D& d;
    E& e;
    F& f;
};


void test()
{
    A a; B b; C c; D d; E e; F f;
    // Different ways to incrementally build the reference holder:
    auto tac = std::tie(a, c); // This is a std::tuple<A&, C&>.
    auto tabc = std::tuple_cat(tac, std::tie(b));
    auto tabcdef = std::tuple_cat(tabc, std::tie(d, f), std::tie(e));

    // We have everything, let's build the object:
    Bar bar(tabcdef);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/pG1R7U

`std::tie` exists precisely to create a tuple of references. We can combine reference tuples using `std::tuple_cat`. And `std::get<T>` allows retrieving exactly the reference we need from a given tuple.

This has:

- Minimum boilerplate: You only have to write `std::get<X&>` in the member initializer list for each referenced type. Nothing else needs to be provided/repeated to use this for more referenced or reference-containing types.
- Complete compile-time safety: If you forget to provide a reference or provide it twice, the compiler will complain. The type system encodes all the necessary information.
- No constraints on the order in which references are added.
- No hand-written template machinery. Using standard facilities instead of hand-written template machinery means you don't introduce bugs/forget corner-cases. It also means users/readers of this approach have nothing they need to wade through (and might run away from, screaming).

I think this is a really simple solution, if only because `std::tuple` and friends already implement all the meta-programming needed here. It's still slightly more complex than "everything in one long list", but I'm pretty sure it'll be worth the tradeoff.

<sup>(My previous hand-written template version exists in edit history. But I realized that `std::tuple` does everything we need here already.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with a run-time check of completeness, I would recommend storing pointers in `Deps` and checking in the constructor of `A` that all the pointers are non-null. That allows you to build `Deps` incrementally and be exactly as safe as before. To perform the non-null check *before* dereferencing the pointers you might need some ugliness (like the comma operator). You might as well store pointers instead of references for the `A` members because (if the constructor checks for null-ness) it is exactly as safe but allows e.g. assignment operators. And makes the null-check easier:

```
struct Deps
{
    B* b;
    C* c;
    D* d;
    E* e;
    F* f;
};

template<class ... Ts>
bool allNonNull(Ts* ... ts)
{
    return ((ts != nullptr) && ...);
}

class A
{
public:
    A(Deps deps) : b(deps.b), c(deps.c), d(deps.d), e(deps.e), f(deps.f)
    {
        assert(allNonNull(b, c, d, e, f));
        if (!allNonNull(b, c, d, e, f))
            /*whatever error handling you want*/;
    }
private:
    B* b;
    C* c;
    D* d;
    E* e;
    F* f;
};
```

The disadvantages are of course that there is no more compile-time check and that there is a lot of code duplication. One might also forget to update the parameters of the null check function.

Comment: Passing pointers and checking them at run-time is a solution I have thought of indeed, but then there are the problems that you mentioned which I personally find worse than a long argument list. Still, thanks for taking the time to write this. Looking forward to the template solution.

Answer (score 0):

With c++20, there is now a better alternative: designated initializers.

When there are references in the constructor arguments, we now *can* use a Deps struct and initialize it elegantly:

```
struct Deps
{
    B &b;
    C &c;
    D &d;
    E &e;
    F &f;
}

class A
{
public:
    A(Deps deps) : b(deps.b), c(deps.c), d(deps.d), e(deps.e), f(deps.f) {}

private:
    B &b;
    C &c;
    D &d;
    E &e;
    F &f;
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    E e;
    F f;
    // Named, type-checked, order-checked initialization! Amazing.
    Deps deps {.b = b, .c = c, .d = d, .e = e, .f = f};
    A a(deps);
    return 0;
}
```